# BeautifulSoup problem and html5lib uninstall install issue

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

When I was running python code it was showing in terminal (python 3.11.4 in my macos Vetura 13.4.1)

*AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'Callable'.*

To fix the issue following commands were applied-

pip3 uninstall beautifulsoup4
pip3 uninstall lxml html5lib
pip3 install beautifulsoup4
pip3 install lxml html5lib

Then it shows
*AttributeError: module 'html5lib.treebuilders' has no attribute '_base'. Did you mean: 'base'?*

pip3 list shows

Package        Version

---

beautifulsoup4 4.12.2
html5lib       1.1
lxml           4.9.3
pip            23.2.1
setuptools     65.5.0
six            1.16.0
soupsieve      2.4.1
webencodings   0.5.1
After downgrading the html5lib by pip3 install --upgrade html5lib==1.0b8 it is again showing **AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'Callable'.**
*Same file was executing smoothly in windows after uninstalling and reinstalling python 3.11.4*

Is there any chance of path issue in macos? Or Should I reinstall python3.11.4?

What should I do now?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It may the version problem, some packages have no such function or classes, you should verify the version.

Comment: Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite Python forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to get more information on how this site works, then [edit] the question with the relevant tags.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following snippet at the beginning of the Python file has fixed the issue

```
import collections.abc
collections.Callable = collections.abc.Callable
```